# Read first line of hosts file on web server

Tags: vb.net

I want to get in label first line of **hosts** file which is **# version X** then put it in label.

```
        'read line of version
    Dim sURL As String = "http://example.com/hosts"
    Dim objNewRequest As WebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(sURL)
        Dim objResponse As WebResponse = objNewRequest.GetResponse
        Dim objStream As New StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream())

    Label7.Text = (objStream.ReadToEnd(1))
```

With that code label7.text return nothing at all. How can i fix that?

Comment: firstly if you go to the same URL in your browser do you get a result?

Comment: if i try to open the file with browser it's automatically download it. Is it because there is no .txt extension ?

Comment: possibly, that and the MIME type. Depends how the server is configured. That could be confusing your HttpWebRequest if it thinks binary data is coming back. Does the file contain any data? P.S. Not sure sharing your hosts file over http is great for security...

Comment: the file is over 1mb and contains 41302 lines